# After how many years of gap did the Dwadash Madhav yearly Parikrama restart?

Tags: vishnu, worship

After how many years did the oldest parikrama on Earth, bhagwan shri dwadash madhav parikrama, tirthraj Prayag of Bhagwan Shri Vishnu restart?

Comment: Bhagwan Shri Dwadash Madhav Yearly Parikrama Tirthraj Prayag was restarted after a long gap of 600 years on 25 November 2015 by Spiritual Guru Swami Shri Ashok Ji Maharaj.